# QtAbstractItemModel endInsertColumns() index out of range

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I'm trying to implement my own model for QtTableWiew. But I'm stuck on problem with inserting column to my model. Here is code for my own insertColumns method:

```
bool DbTableModel::insertColumns(int column, int count, const QModelIndex &parent) {
   Q_D(DbTableModel);

    beginInsertColumns(parent,column,column+count);
    d->table->insertColumn(column, "");
    endInsertColumns();

    return true;
}
```

Here is how insertColumns is called:

```
insertColumns(index,1);
```

Here is implementation of insertColumn in d->table:

```
void XMLTable::insertColumn(int index, QString name)
{
    Q_D(XMLTable);

    d->columns.insert(d->columns.begin() + index + 1,name);

    for(int i = 0;i < d->data.count();i++)
    {
        if(index + 1 >= d->data[i].count())
        {
            d->data[i].append("");
        }
        else
        {
            d->data[i].insert(index + 1,"");
        }
    }
}
```

The code throws error on endInsertColumns() in insertColumnsMethod method:

```
 ASSERT failure in QVector<T>::operator[]: "index out of range", file ..\..\..\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\include\QtCore/qvector.h, line 396
 Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
 Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
```

My question is: **Why endInsertColumns throws error and how to repair it?**

Thanks for help

Comment: What is the `index` value in `insertColumns(index,1);`?

Comment: Its index of currently selected column. In debug this value looks good and insertColumn method in XMLTable works without problem.

Comment: Yes, but what is its value? You have to understand, that at some point the index value you use is out of boundary of your vector, and you need to know why it is happen. If it is look good and works without problem, what is your question?

Comment: Before it is called there is this condition `if(index >= 0 && index <= columnCount())`. When index = columnCount then new column is added.

Comment: change <= columnCount() to < columnCount()

The range goes from 0 to N-1, being N the number of elements.

Comment: This didnt solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found solution myself. The problem was in beginInsertColumns method. When i tried to call it with this:

```
beginInsertColumns(parent,column,column+count);
```

than last index was moved by 1. So I solved it with modifying calling of method insertColumns like this:

```
insertColumns(index,0);
```

I thank you for your help.